# Is there a css-only way to do background blur in IE11?

Tags: css, blur, css-filters

I want to make the background visible but blurred when a popup is opened. I am not asking about image blur, I am asking about adding blur to the page, and I want to know if there is currently any CSS-only solution?

There are other questions similar to this; however, some of them ask for any solution including javascript solution while others search for image blur and not background blur and others are very old so maybe there is some new CSS-only solution using new browsers features.

**None of the other questions in Stackoverflow have a CSS-only solution for ie11 to the question i am asking.**

The non-CSS solutions I am aware of are:

1. The solution which uses javascript uses libraries like http://quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
2. To create an image of the background using libraries like html2canvas: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas and then insert the image inside an inline svg and apply svg filter blur to it.

I have checked and verified that none of the following works in IE11:

```
filter: blur(7px);
-webkit-filter: blur(7px);
filter: url(/images/blur.svg#blur);
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf9,<svg%20version='1.1'%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter%20id='blur'><feGaussianBlur%20stdDeviation='7'%20/></filter></svg>#blur");
-moz-filter: blur(7px);
-o-filter: blur(7px);
-ms-filter: blur(7px);
/* This only works for older IE. For newer IE using javascript is suggested here: http://thenewcode.com/534/Crossbrowser-Image-Blur-with-CSS */
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='7');
```

It will be very nice to get an official answer from someone from Microsoft that this is not possible if that's the case.

Comment: to blur the page but one element means to set page content into a common wrapper that you blur, and have this other element be a sibbling but a child. For older IE filter with the proper prefix works IE5t o 9

Comment: @GCyrillus I know that and thats what I did with the code above which works for all browsers except IE11 and that's why I asked this stackoverflow question.

I need a way to add blur to that common wrapper you are talking about which will work in IE11 and i prefer a css-only solution.

Comment: @GuyL. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @swenedo I added opacity to all elements (*) inside the wrapper of body elements which is the son of <body> and sibling of the popup. Added this according to body-ie11 css class which is added to body by javascript which on load checks if its ie-11.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.  Microsoft does not support this CSS functionality for IE 11, as explained here:

http://thenewcode.com/534/Cross-browser-Image-Blur-with-CSS

You can use this:

http://quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

...but it's not a CSS-only solution, aside from the not-so CSS-only solution of loading an already blurred image or a blur.png (semi-transparent gray) if IE11 is used.